# cron tab to execute rails commands

Tags: mysql, ruby, ubuntu

i am running a cron tab for every 5 minutes,it contains an .sh files which need to be executed ,where that .sh file consists of ruby code....one thing i can't understand that when i am executing the .sh file directly in terminal its get execute,but the same thing in crontab fails..my entry in crontab follows :

```
1) mysqldump -uroot -p'myPassword' redmine144 > redmine144_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M).sql;

2) cd /home/ror/Projects/redmine144/;
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p194@redmine144
bundle exec rake "hb:project_progress"
```

First one to take backup and it is working fine.
Second one to run some ruby rake task(not working form cron tab)

Comment: yeah, RVM and crontab require some tweaking to work together.

Comment: next time don't include your passwords in questions

Answer (score 2):

usually crontab output in not directed to stdout so you check your out put in /var/log/cron file which contains the cron logs. you can add the output and redirect the error, for more see http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/crontab-log/ and check what error pops upp and you'll be able to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Making RVM work with cron is really tricky. I'll share a snippet from my own crontab that is proven to work (with system-wide RVM) - just make sure your app path has a `.rvmrc` specifying the ruby version and gemset.

```
MAILTO=mymail@gmail.com
SHELL=/bin/bash
? ? ? ? ? source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh; cd /app/home/path && bundle exec rake whatever_you_need RAILS_ENV=production
```

`SHELL` is important.

The `MAILTO` is there to aid debugging and could be removed later.

Don't forget to substitute your schedule for the question marks.